# Imprimir una consulta en un JTextArea

Tags: java, sql, base-de-datos, textarea

Estoy realizando una aplicación Java, con interfaz gráfica, conectada a una base de datos. La cuestión es que cuando pulso el botón de consultas me funciona a la perfección imprimiendolo por consola, sin embargo, me gustaría saber como puedo imprimir estas consultas en un jTextArea en vez de en consola. He probado a hacerlo con *jTextAreaConsultas.getText();* pero no me ha funcionado. Dejo a continuación el código del *jButtonConsultas* y el código de los métodos a los que llamo.

**El código del jButtonConsultas del jFrame es:**

```
private void jButtonConsultasActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        String[] opciones = {"Primera consulta con Statement", "Segunda consulta con Statement", "Consulta con PreparedStatement"};
        int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(rootPane, "¿Que opción deseas consultar?",
                "Consulta con Statement", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
                null, opciones, opciones[0]);
               
        if (result == 0) {
            gestor.consulta_Statement();
            jTextAreaConsultas.getText();
        } else if (result == 1) {
            gestor.segundConsulta_Statement();
            jTextAreaConsultas.getText();
        } else if (result == 2) {
            gestor.consulta_PreparedStatement("PlayStation 4", 20);
            jTextAreaConsultas.getText();
        } else if (result == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {
            // No se hace nada
        }        
    }
```

**Los códigos de los métodos de las consultas son:**

```
public void consulta_Statement() {
        Statement sta;

        try {
            sta = conn1.createStatement();

            String query = "SELECT * FROM desarrollador WHERE pais = 'Japón';";
            ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(query);

            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("ID: " + rs.getInt("id") + ", Desarrollador: " + rs.getString("nombre")
                        + ", Pais: " + rs.getString("pais"));
            }

            rs.close();
            sta.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }

    public void segundConsulta_Statement() {
        Statement sta;

        try {
            sta = conn1.createStatement();

            String query = "SELECT d.nombre Desarrollador, j.nombre Videojuego, j.genero Género, j.plataforma Plataforma, j.precio Precio FROM desarrollador d, juego j WHERE d.id = j.id_desarrollador;";
            ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(query);

            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("Desarrollador: " + rs.getString("Desarrollador") + ", Videojuego: " + rs.getString("Videojuego")
                        + ", Genero: " + rs.getString("Género") + ", Plataforma: " + rs.getString("Plataforma")
                        + ", Precio: " + rs.getString("Precio"));
            }

            rs.close();
            sta.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }

    public void consulta_PreparedStatement(String plataforma, float precio) {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM juego WHERE plataforma = ? AND precio < ?;";

        try {
            PreparedStatement pst = conn1.prepareStatement(query);
            pst.setString(1, plataforma);
            pst.setFloat(2, precio);

            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("ID: " + rs.getInt("id") + ", Nombre: " + rs.getString("nombre")
                        + ", Genero: " + rs.getString("genero") + ", Plataforma: "
                        + rs.getString("plataforma") + ", Fecha de salida: " + rs.getString("fecha_salida")
                        + ", Precio: " + rs.getString("precio"));
            }

            rs.close();
            pst.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola María, con **getText()** le estás pidiendo al JTextArea que te de el texto que contiene, para colocar texto en el debes usar **setText( "lo que quiero que muestre" );**, en código sería jTextAreaConsultas.setText( "algo para mostrar" );

Comment: Tambien probé con un jTextAreaConsultas.setText( gestor.consulta_Statement() ); pero no tampoco funciona

Comment: **gestor.consulta_Statement()** está declarado como **void**, osea que no devuelve nada, deberías gestionar dentro del while, la carga de una variable tipo String que luego retornas.

Comment: antes del while declaras **String salida = "";**,  dentro del mismo **salida += "ID: " + rs.getInt("id") + ", Desarrollador: " + rs.getString("nombre")
                        + ", Pais: " + rs.getString("pais") + "\n";**, prueba y dime si te funciona. al final del método agrega **return salida;** y cambia en la declaración del método void por String.

Comment: Ya me funciona! Muchas gracias

Comment: Un placer ayudarte.